# Is there anything new about playing Valhalla again?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

After finishing FFXIII-2, you unlock Valhalla. Entering it just executes the same battle scene as the beginning of the game (Lightning vs Caius).

Is there anything new about it? Am I able to get something I couldn't before? Extra rewards/sequences etc? Or is it unlocked just for the sake of collection/completion (which seems nice)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is the DLC, there is nothing new you can do. Mainly it is just there and unlocked for your leisure now, instead of starting a new game.

Answer (score 2):

No there is nothing new about it and is just there for the sake of collection/ completion.

Source's: Me, Strategy guide